# Is this function can be a good way to preload in jquery?

Tags: jquery

is this function that i wrote in jquery, will be a good way to preload?
thank you

```
function loader(){

        imgTag('#check');

        function imgTag(whereToAppend){
            var image = 'image.jpg';

            $(whereToAppend).append('<img id="imgWrapper">');

            $('#imgWrapper').attr('src', image).hide().one('load',function(){
                $(this).fadeIn('slow');
            })
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the following solution to preload images:

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        // Alternatively you could use:
        // (new Image()).src = this;
    });
}

// Usage:

preload([
    'img/imageName.jpg',
    'img/anotherOne.jpg',
    'img/blahblahblah.jpg'
]);
```

Source: [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Comment: jQuery returns a collection, and you only need the first element. Hence you use `[0]` or `.get(0)`

Comment: so the img tag is hide until image is fully downloaded?

Comment: You need to show the images manually. They are just preloaded here. So you get rid of the loading-effect of the images. Just add the images that youre planning to show in the array and show them as usual whenever you like

Comment: ok! thanks for our quick reply. but i'm still confused of preloading...

Comment: as i understood the array of images will added on DOM but they are not showed on page still i call them. isn't it?

Comment: They are preloaded but not appended to the DOM in this answer. However, there are answers in the thread that i linked to that has that kind of solutions as well. Just pick the one that suits you best